# What is the proper way to su as a local user from Udev?

Tags: udev, su

When running commands related to displays, it seems that commands like `xrandr` don't work until they are run as a local user.

However, when running scripts as a local user via a udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="su -l --shell=/bin/bash -c /opt/echo-foo.sh chris"
```

With `echo-foo.sh` defined as:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "foo"
```

---

Preparing `udev` for debugging:

```
udevadm control --log-priority=debug
journalctl -f # tail the logs
```

---

I get the following `udev` error when plugging/unplugging my monitor:

```
Starting 'su -l --shell=/bin/bash -c /opt/echo-foo.sh chris'
Sucessfully forked off '(spawn)' as PID #####
Process 'su -l --shell=/bin/bash -c /opt/echo-foo.sh chris' failed with exit code 1.
```

However, from root, the command works. Is there a proper way to do this, and I am missing some detail?

---

Other details:

`-rwxr-xr-x root root 3.3K ... /opt/echo-foo.sh`

-- 3.3K: my true script is commented out.

Comment: See `systemctl cat systemd-udevd`. If the `[Service]` section includes `SystemCallFilter=` lines or other sandboxing directives, those might be causing `su` to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/bin/sh -c '...'
```

-- is required  for things to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To allow commands like `xrandr` to affect your session from "outside" it, you will need to supply it a valid `DISPLAY` environment variable, sometimes also a `XAUTHORITY` variable (depends on distro & desktop environment), and the command needs to be able to access the `/tmp/.X11-unix/X<display number>` socket and the X session cookie file.

The default pathname for the session cookie file is `~/.Xauthority`; if the file is not in the default location, then you'll need the `XAUTHORITY` variable to indicate the full pathname.

The X server does not actually check the user ID associated with incoming connections: it relies on the fact that the session cookie file is normally protected so that only root and the file's owner will be able to access it.

In other words, you might not need `su` at all: just

```
SUBSYSTEM=="drm", ACTION=="change", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/chris/.Xauthority xrandr ...'"
```

might be enough, unless your home directory is on a NFS share that's exported with a `root_squash` option in effect, or something similar.

Comment: upvoted as it was helpful.  I wound up sticking with `su` since I handle the DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY w/in my script.